# Chrome accept to run enter Angular 2 web

Tags: google-chrome, angular, webstorm

I'm building a small app in Angular 2 using WebStorm.

When I press <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> to start the web on Chrome I get an error that my connection is not private and someone try to steal information from my localhost.

> NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.
>   This is the address: https://localhost:63342/angular2/index.html

**Additional information:** My firewall is not active and there is no antivirus installed.

```
npm -v is 2.14.12
node -v is 4.3.1
```

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608922/self-signed-ssl-cert-for-localhost-how-to-make-trusted

Comment: The URL uses secure connection (`https` as protocol in your URL) and WebStorm does not provide any SSL certificate (AFAIK) for their built-in simple web server (it is what you are using). If it provides, it would be self signed. In both cases Chrome would be correct. **Possible solution:** change URL to use plain `http`

Comment: @LazyOne How do I do that?

Comment: Well ... please check where you are using that URL. It could be one of your Run/Debug Configurations (`Run | Edit Configurations...`). But it also could be taken from your Deployment entry (Check your Settings/Preferences screen -- search for `deployment` in search box). BTW -- does it work if you just change to http in browser address bar?

Comment: I couldnt find anywhere Https, only http. this is the adress in the config: _http_://localhost:63342/angular2/index.html

Comment: In such case I do not know where the `https` is taken from. The only other place I would look at is actual your app -- it can make such internal redirect. I suggest: clear browser cache (as much as you can: cookies etc); restart browser; open dev tools on network tab; type your URL with `http` in it -- see if it will be redirected to `https` one. If yes -- start looking -- was it server response or did it happen after page was loaded etc.

Comment: Try running your app by opening it outside of webstorm and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you very much. Clearing browser cache was the missing part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggle with this, follow [kellen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate).
After that Use @LazyOne 's good advice and clear browser cache (All of it).